# Using localectl on Arch, Failed to issue method call: Invalid Locale data

Tags: locale

Using Arch.

```
$ localectl status
System Locale: n/a

VC Keymap: n/a
X11 Layout: n/a
```

Okay cool, so I just do set locale, right?

```
 $ localectl list-locales
 en_US.utf8
```

...cool, I'll use en_US.utf8

```
 localectl set-locale en_US.utf8
 Failed to issue method call: Invalid Locale data...
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: This should not be closed as "cannot be reproduced". I had the same problem and arrived here via search and found the solution.

Comment: Going by the number of upvotes, it looks like quite a few of us could reproduce this error message by mis-using the `localectl` command. :)  In my case, it was on a CentOS 7 system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Never mind, I was just using it wrongly.

From `info localectl`:

> ```
> ...this [command] takes one or more assignments such as LANG=en_US.utf8
> ```

Comment: Anyone know how I set the syntax highlighting for a post to bash?

Comment: You can force it with: `<!-- language: lang-bsh -->` (it is generally triggered by the tags)...

Comment: To clarify, instead of `localectl set-locale en_US.utf8`, you used `localectl set-locale LANG="en_US.utf8"`.

Comment: @jasonwryan, I suspect `bsh` is means beanshell

Comment: ... and log out and log in again to take effect.